# SQL error - Cursor malformed or incomplete

Tags: cursor, oracle-sqldeveloper, malformed

My goal here is to have a nested cursor running in loops, so that it displays a section name and number, then all of the people within that section.

First the code.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 4000

DECLARE
  search VARCHAR2(20) := 'Summer 2007';
  CURSOR cur_class IS
    SELECT call_id, sec_num, c_sec_id
    FROM course_section
    INNER JOIN course ON course_section.course_id = course.course_id
    INNER JOIN term ON course_section.term_id = term.term_id
    WHERE term.term_desc = search
    ORDER BY course.call_id;
  f_cur cur_class%ROWTYPE;
  CURSOR cur_students IS
    SELECT c_sec_id, s_first, s_last
    FROM enrollment
    INNER JOIN student ON enrollment.s_id = student.s_id
    INNER JOIN course_section ON enrollment.c_sec_id = course_section.c_sec_id
    WHERE enrollment.c_sec_id IS NOT NULL;
  f_cur_stu cur_students%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  OPEN cur_class;
  LOOP
    FETCH cur_class INTO f_cur;
    EXIT WHEN cur_class%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(f_cur.call_id || ' Sec. ' || f_cur.sec_num);
      FOR f_cur_stu IN cur_students LOOP
        IF f_cur.c_sec_id = f_cur_stu.c_sec_id THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(f_cur_stu.s_first || ' ' || f_cur_stu.s_last);
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur_class;
END;
```

Here is the error message:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 16, column 11:
PL/SQL: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
ORA-06550: line 12, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 11, column 10:
PLS-00341: declaration of cursor 'CUR_STUDENTS' is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 17, column 13:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 26, column 29:
PLS-00364: loop index variable 'F_CUR_STU' use is invalid
ORA-06550: line 26, column 9:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

If I comment out the whole second cursor creation AND the nested loop, the first loop works, listing for me the section name and number as desired.

The issue occurs when I try the second cursor, cur_students. I don't know how the cursor is malformed/incomplete and what I can do to complete it. I've tried other WHERE clauses and it's always the same thing.

EDIT: A picture of the table structure:
[image: Table Structure]

Answer (score 0):

The usual suspect is as if your table `enrollment` does not have a column named `c_sec_id`.

Can you also share the table structure?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the comment! I uploaded the table structure, but it was as fg78nc answered below. But I can see why you suggested it might be that c_sec_id didn't exist in the enrollment table. Thank you for your help and your time.

Answer (score 0):

1)    `SELECT c_sec_id, s_first, s_last`

Column `c_sec_id` is present in both of the `enrollment` and `course_section` tables. You have to prefix it with the table name, i.e. either `enrollment.c_sec_id` or `course_section.c_sec_id`, otherwise it is not clear to the compiler from which of above mentioned tables you want to retrieve it.

2)
  `f_cur_stu cur_students%ROWTYPE;`

You do not need this declaration, because  `f_cur_stu` in `FOR f_cur_stu IN cur_students LOOP` is implicitly created variable by cursor loop itself.

Comment: THANK YOU! That is all it was! I didn't realize I needed to specify course_section.c_sec_id in the SELECT statement. I mean, it makes sense once I think about it and say it out loud. Thank you again! Once I added "course_section." to the front of c_sec_id it worked perfectly, no errors.